# How to create a positive Int64 hash (>=1) from a string, must be consistent across all hardware, using DotNet C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

Using C# and DotNet, how to take a string and convert into a unique hash code number. The most important, **hash code is >=1**. The following guidelines should apply:

1. Hash code must be reasonably unique per input string, similar to SHA256. Naturally, the datatype being a positive Int64 caps the uniqueness to 9223372036854775807!
2. Hash code must Int64
3. Only positive numbers, no negatives allowed, no zero, >=1 only.
4. Consistent across all hardware.
5. Ideally a high performance solution, though this method will not be used extensively in high throughput use cases.

Use case

1. The input string set have lengths of each string between 1 to 500 chars.
2. The hash codes will only be used to test uniqueness in the same set of roughly 1 million items. An item in set A, will not be compared with set B.
3. Thus, essentially, this is **not** for a global set of possible strings.

Example method signature:

`long hash = ToHashPositiveInt64(@"some text value");`

Ideally someway of using SHA256, or [SpookilySharp](https://github.com/JonHanna/SpookilySharp) or another library and adapt so can output >=1 hashcodes.

Comment: "a unique hash code" - given that there are more than 2^63 possible strings, uniqueness cannot be achieved alongside your other constraints. So you've either misunderstood the requirement or you've got an impossible to achieve requirement. Either way, I'd suggest going back and revisiting it.

Comment: Good point @Damien_The_Unbeliever, have revised

Comment: Take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Comment: What is the reason that you don't just use a `HashSet<string>` instance? Do you want to avoid having to store the strings along with their hashes?

Comment: Good question @TheodorZoulias. The requirement is to output "hash code positive numbers" for a business requirement. The HashSet is not of use in this scenario.